# How to copy text in a table cell in Notion?

Tags: copy-paste, notion

When I select a table cell and copy it, all I have is a list of links. I want to copy text only. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a table with the cells you want to copy is in the first column (i.e. they are row header). Copy text in there will copy text

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to change the way you are pasting. On Windows try pasting as `Ctrl + shift + V` instead of `Ctrl + v` -- this should paste the values only.